# return generic table from method in dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

How to return generic type of table in DBContext I tried this but getting error??

can anybody help to solve this issue.

```
    public  T  DeviceExist<T>(string DeviceId, int ImageId)
    {
     return DBContext.T.Where(d => d.DeviceId == DeviceId && d.ImageId == ImageId).FirstOrDefault();           
    }
```

Comment: what you want may be `DbContext.Set<T>()`

Comment: i want some thing like this return DBContext.Set<T>().Where(d => d.DeviceId == DeviceId); but getting error ? there is no intelliscence

Comment: and i want to return generic class in return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your generic type `T` is inheriting from a base class having properties `DeviceId` and `ImageId`, you can use:

```
DBContext.Set<T>().Where(d => d.DeviceId == DeviceId && d.ImageId == ImageId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Don't forget to specify your base class from which `T` is inheriting in the `where` constraints of the generic class/repository.

Comment: guyz thank you so much ....finally problem solved

Comment: if i Update Model from db it will generate all classess and remove my interface implementation ?

Comment: and again i will go and implement IEntity interface again? so this is so bad ?how do i handle this issue here?

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement, and whether it is at all possible or not, but considering your case, it might be best to switch to EF code-first. Then you can generate your database table from the code itself and not the other way around, which eliminates the possibility of removing inheritance chain. Again I am not sure whether switching to code first is an option for your or not.